# nginx-gridfs: control which documents in a collection can be served via nginx vs my app?

Tags: mongodb, nginx, gridfs

I'm doing some planning for replacing an existing solution with mongodb and potentially using the GridFS functionality for static assets. One question that I have is if I choose to front GridFS with nginx, is there a way to control which assets in a collection may be served directly from nginx versus which asset requests need to be directed to my application?

The reason I ask is that some security checks are done for certain assets and those assets have always been served out of the app itself (and will need to continue to be, at least for now).

I was thinking, I could probably just add a property on the file descriptors stored in nginx that is something like `isPublished`. Could I instruct nginx-gridfs to respect this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there have been requests for this functionality but the project is largely abandoned by contributors. The applicable ticket is here: https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs/issues/24